# Why do the last two functions work, but not the first?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have three different functions that should do the same thing, populate an array with resolved Promises, but it's not working for the first example.

Here's my code:

```js
(async() => {
  const items = [];
  const someFn = async() => {
    const v = await Promise.resolve(10);
    items.push(Math.random());
    return Promise.resolve(v * 10);
  }
  const arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    arr.push(someFn);
  }
  await Promise.all(arr);
  console.log("item 1", items);
})();

(async() => {
  const items = [];
  const someFn = async() => {
    const v = await Promise.resolve(10);
    items.push(Math.random());
    return Promise.resolve(v * 10);
  }
  const arr = [...Array(10).keys()].map(someFn)
  await Promise.all(arr);
  console.log("items 2", items);
})();

(async() => {
  const items = [];
  const someFn = async() => {
    const v = await Promise.resolve(10);
    items.push(Math.random());
    return Promise.resolve(v * 10);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    await someFn();
  }
  console.log("items 3", items);
})()
```

This is the output:

```
item 1 []

items 2 [ 0.7450904427103939,
  0.37106667256699555,
  0.12035280341441346,
  0.265221052932904,
  0.7775494303685422,
  0.4872532010723445,
  0.6497680191919464,
  0.2570485072009576,
  0.5613137531648884,
  0.95109416178435 ]

items 3 [ 0.25328649499657585,
  0.5452758396760038,
  0.7274346878509064,
  0.9306670111476503,
  0.22942578229725785,
  0.32547900377461625,
  0.9722902638678983,
  0.9964743517593542,
  0.2828162584401659,
  0.7672256760378469 ]
```

Notice how `item 1` is an empty array.

Answer (score 5):

That's because in the first example, `someFn` is never executed:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    arr.push(someFn);
}
await Promise.all(arr);
```

This part just pushes functions into the `arr` variable, it doesn't run them, thus not creating Promises and never filling the `items` array.

On the other hand, the other examples run the function `someFn`:

```
const arr = [...Array(10).keys()].map(someFn)
```

This fills the `arr` array with 10 executions of `someFn` (`map` executes them with the current value (0-9), the index (also 0-9) and the array itself).

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    await someFn();
}
```

And this obviously runs `someFn` in a loop.

To make the first example work, push the result of the function into the array:

```js
(async () => {
    const items = [];
    const someFn = async () => {
        const v = await Promise.resolve(10);
        items.push(Math.random());
        return Promise.resolve(v * 10);
    }
    const arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        arr.push(someFn()); // <-- () added
    }
    await Promise.all(arr);
    console.log("item 1", items);
})();
```

Comment: it is very confusing how promises works in javascript land haha, Thank you

Comment: Yep, it can feel like that sometimes ;-)

Answer (score 1):

you’re pushing  `someFn` but you want `someFn()`. note we’re calling the function.